# How to expand canvas depending on device

Tags: android, android-canvas, tizen

These days i am coding game application as 
a basic canvas size like 480-width and 800-height.

so I have to expand canvas depending on tizen smart device

I wondering how to do this.

I had finished this work in Android like this:

```
ScaleX = canvas.getWidth() / 480f;   

ScaleY = canvas.getHeight() / 800f;    

canvas.scale( ScaleX, ScaleY );
```

but, I am wondering how to do this on Tizen API
Do you know how to handle this problem in Tizen?